# If IsError Function

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

first time post. I am not a programmer by trade, this is just for personal use at work to make my job more efficient and easy, so apologies for what might be a elementary question.

I have searched for examples to answer my question, but can't seem to find an answer that seems to work quite right for what I'm doing.

I want code to look in Row1 of my spreadsheet. If it finds a cell with the text "WarrantyCode", then select that cell. Otherwise, find the first empty cell in Row1 and make it "WarrantyCode"

Here's the code I have.

```
Sub WCFInd()
If IsError(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sku").Rows(1).Find("WarrantyCode").Select) Then
Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.Value = "WarrantyCode"
           Else
                 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sku").Rows(1).Find("WarrantyCode").Select
End If
End Sub
```

When Row1 does have a cell with "WarrantyCode" it selects the cell properly. But when it doesn't, I get the Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sku").Rows(1).Find("WarrantyCode").Select
```

is selecting a cell, not giving a reference to a cell.  The syntax for the `IsError` function is `IsError( expression )` which means something must be passed as a parameter, and you are effectively not passing any parameter at all.

So remove the `.Select` and just use the following line:

```
If IsError(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sku").Rows(1).Find("WarrantyCode")) Then
```

and your code won't crash.

However, what you are probably trying to do is:

```
Sub WCFInd()
If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sku").Rows(1).Find("WarrantyCode") Is Nothing Then
Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.Value = "WarrantyCode"
           Else
                 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sku").Rows(1).Find("WarrantyCode").Select
End If
End Sub
```

and that code would be better written (in my opinion anyway) as

```
Sub WCFInd()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sku").Rows(1)
        If .Find("WarrantyCode") Is Nothing Then
            .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = "WarrantyCode"
        End If
        .Find("WarrantyCode").Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Both options worked perfect. And I cannot tell you enough how much I appreciate the detailed explanations as to why I had the crash, and how better to go about it. Huge help as I continue to learn how to more effectively use VBA code. Thanks a million.

Comment: @Comintern - Thanks, I have edited my answer.  (I originally ended up on the Visual Studio page when I googled the parameters and **it** requires an Object, but it is doing something completely different anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
Sub UsingFind()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sku").Rows(1).Find("WarrantyCode")
    If r Is Nothing Then
        Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Select
    Else
        r.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Worked great!